# Is it true that $10^n + 1$ is never a perfect square? If so, how can you prove it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm working on a problem and right now I want to prove that $10^n + 1$ is never a perfect square. I know that for even values of $n$, the expression is not a perfect square since two positive perfect squares cannot differ by $1$ and both $1$ and $10^{2m}$ are perfect squares. I just don't know how to prove it for odd $n$s.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint:   $m^2-1=(m-1)(m+1)=10^n$

Comment: As shown in the AoPS thread [Interesting NT](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1398536p7818715), consider modulo $3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering squares in $\bmod 9$, we can see that every perfect square must be $0,1,4,7\mod 9$ (these are the quadratic residues $\bmod 9$). However, $10^n+1\equiv 2\mod 9$, so it can never be a square.

Comment: Actually, as I indicated in my question comment, considering $\mod 3$ also works since squares can only be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Oh yes, that's probably a bit easier. Mod 9 was my first instinct.

Answer (score 0):

Note: In any base $b$, $10_{b}$ means $b$.

We know that $10^{n}$ is always a perfect power, so if $10^{n}+1$ were ever a square number, then it would contradict the Catalan’s Conjecture, as the only non-trival consecutive perfect powers are $8$ and $9$.